# twitteR package that returns name of user with tweet with specific hashtag in R

Tags: r, twitter, social-networking

I am trying to get a list of tweets for a specific hashtag, like [here](http://davetang.org/muse/2013/04/06/using-the-r_twitter-package/). I also need to get the actual name of the user, so not "@hadleywickham" but "Hadley Wickham" but with most users their user name is @joemomma when their real name is "Joe Smith", so I can't just subset the data. I have been using code like this: `r_stats<- searchTwitter("#Rstats", n=1500, cainfo="cacert.pem")`(mine only works without the  to return the `"cainfo="cacert.pem"` part). Do I make a df of all the user_names than use another twitteR function to output the actual name? If so which one, how do I do it?I looked through the [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twitteR/twitteR.pdf) but I'm still unsure.

I am using 64 bit windows R and version 3.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `twitteR::twListToDF` to convert your status object (`r_stats`) to a data.frame. One of the columns in that is (IIRC) the user's real name.